# HTML Redirecting with text before the domain

Tags: html

I'm working on a Website and I was wondering how can I check if it has some text before the domain, for instance:

> **shop**.website.com

If it starts with shop. before the domain, then I want to redirect them to another page.

How do I do that?

Comment: you can simply create a subdomain with name shop on your webserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expression for checking whether there is text before the domain.

example:

```
<script>
function myFunction() 
{
  var str = "shop.world.com";
  var patt = /(\w*)\.\w*\.\w*/g;
  var result = patt.exec(str);
  if( result!=null)
  {
      if(result[1]=="shop")
      {
          //redirect the page
          window.location.href="anotherPage.html";
      }
  }

}
</script>
```

If the result is not null then there is text before the domain.As we have remembered the text before the domain by using parenthesis in our regular expression we can easily compare it with string "shop" and if it matches then redirect the page.

for more information on regular expression you can visit this page

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.href` will provide you the URL of the current page.

Use `window.location.replace(..)` to redirect the user.

Although in your case you may configure sub-domains on your web server. Refer the following link for more on sub-domains:
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-is-a-subdomain-name-how-do-i-create-and-delete-one